# for loop condition in C

Tags: c, for-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{   
  for(5;2;2)    printf("Hello"); 
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to learn C. I encountered this for-loop. When I compiled this code I got an error 'Irreducible expression tree'.
The for loop I know looks like this

```
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
```

First assigning value, then checking condition, then changing initial value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. What do you think the output is?  What happened when you compiled it?  Ran it?  How do you think it should work?  How does a `for` loop work?  What does your text book have to say when explaining how `for` loops work? Questions like this which show no effort tend to be down-voted heavily.  This is very basic stuff that is explained in text books. People don't often write such code (there is no computation in the loop controls), but you should be asking about how to adapt what you know of `for` loops to account for this.

Comment: Don't forget to output a newline at the end of `printf()` statements.  You get unhelpful results if you omit the newline.

Comment: Did you run it? What output did you get?

Comment: It is surprising that you got an error 'irreducible expression tree' — that sounds like an internal compiler error.  The code should compile, and once it starts running, it will continue running until you get bored and stop it or your machine crashes.  Consider reporting a bug to the compiler's maintainers — if you've got a current or almost current version of the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop has the structure:

```
for(init; cond; incdec)
```

If `cond` is a constant number other than zero, the loop executes infinitely.
Having a number `2` evaluates the cond to be true always.

Answer (score 2):

The correct code would be like this...

```
#include <stdio.h> //including the library
// Main Function 
int main(){

    int i; // Declaring the variable

    // i = 0 Initializing variable i
    // i < 5, so if i >= 5 it will not execute the for loop
    // i ++, increment the variable i by 1 for every loop

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Hello");
    }
}
```

In your code, you didn't declare any variable and put some unknown things. The compiler will take it as always true and execute `printf("Hello");` infinite times.

Answer (score 1):

This generates an infinite for-loop because the checking condition of the for-loop is always non-zero or True

```
for(5;2;2) //the checking condition is always 2 which is non-zero or true in other sense
```

The statement condition check is inside the parenthesis after first semicolon(`;`). In your case it is only a `2` which is considered `True`.

**Output**

```
HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHell......
```